# How to log out from network path

Tags: windows, networking

I have successfully logged onto a network path. But now I need to log onto that same path with different credentials.

The problem is that when I navigate to that path, I no longer get a login dialog, even after rebooting!

Is there any way to log out of that path so that next time I try to navigate there the login dialog will appear?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would check to see if it stored any credentials for that network path in the credential manager.

1. From the Start menu, select Control Panel.
2. Click User Accounts.
3. Click Credential Manager.
4. In the Windows Credentials and Generic Credentials section, remove
   any stored credentials referencing shares, network drives or
   similar: Click  (Details).
5. Click Remove from vault.
6. Click Yes on the warning box.
7. Repeat these steps until you remove all of the credentials
   associated with network shares.
8. Close the Control Panel window.

Comment: I didn't even stop to think the creds were saved.  Good call.

Comment: That worked, thanks. Note that on my copy of Windows 10, the option is "Accounts". And while I couldn't see an option for "Credential Manager", I was able to search for it and it came up.

Comment: @JonathanWood I am glad it is working now.

Answer (score 5):

The only way I know if is to do it from a command line:

```
net use \\someserver\share /DELETE
```

Comment: I tried that but it seemed to have no effect. Now when I try it again, `The network connection could not be found.`

Comment: if you type `net use` and press enter, you should get a list of all network shares you're connected to currently.  Also, have you tried connecting using the `net use` command?  i.e. `net use \\server\share /user:domain\user`

Comment: This remove it from the list, but does not affect the stored credentials. Using the \\Server again allow you in.